# Search ID by : APP_USER apex oracle

Tags: sql, oracle11g, oracle-apex

I have an authorization table. There's a Username, Login and Password I want. Also I have P1_item, I want to assign this variable Username, when I write a log in log everything works and when the APP_USER. does not work

```
CREATE TABLE test
(
name  varcahar2(10),
login varcahar2(10),
pass NUMBER(10)
);
INSERT INTO test
        VALUES ('Andrii', 'log', 111);



select name from test where login = '&APP_USER.'

select name from test where login = 'log'
```

Comment: If you want more help, you're going to have to meet us halfway. Provide some details about where you're putting this code. Make a test case on apex.oracle.com.

Comment: Thank you, I've already fixed the issue "LOWER (: APP_USER)"

Answer (score 1):

Don't use `&APP_USER.` as this is a substitution string - instead, bind the variable directly using `:APP_USER`, e.g.

```
select name from test where login = :APP_USER
```

Comment: Thank you, but it didn't help

Answer (score 0):

There is no value "APP_USER" in the login column...

Comment: & APP_USER. is a global variable

Answer (score 0):

you can use V function ([more details](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E59726_01/doc.50/e39147/bldapp_item.htm#HTMDB25335)), but it is not recommended in SQL:

```
select name from test where login = V('APP_USER');
```

or you can bind the variable:

```
select name from test where login = :APP_USER;
```

Comment: Thank you, but it didn't help